# How to return two in line if-else statements in one method? JAVA

Tags: java, methods, return

I am trying to return two outcomes from the blankEnd() method. I want to test if this.end1 is 0 and also test if this.end2 is 0. How can I combine these two return statements? Thanks!

```
public boolean blankEnd() {
return this.end1 == 0 ? true : false;
return this.end2 == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: An array of boolean maybe? A method can only ever return one thing so if you want multiple booleans, return an array of them.

Comment: With a single `boolean` return value, what would you want to return if `this.end1 == 0` and `this.end2 != 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `&&`

```
return (this.end1 == 0 && this.end2 == 0)? true : false;
```

**EDIT:** In fact if you just want to return `true/false` then you don't need conditional statement:

Simply use :

```
return (this.end1 == 0 && this.end2 == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have four cases:

```
this.end1  this.end2
       0          0
       0      not 0
   not 0          0
   not 0      not 0
```

If you want to return a single `boolean` value, you will need to decide what you want to return for each combination. Then you can code up the appropriate logical expression. Since there are four rows and each row has two possible return values (`true` or `false`), it's possible to define 16 different functions here. For instance, if you want to return `true` if either `end1` or `end2` is true, then you could use:

```
return this.end1 == 0 || this.end2 == 0;
```

If you want to return two `boolean` values, you can return an array:

```
public boolean[] blankEnd() {
    return new boolean[] { this.end1 == 0, this.end2 == 0};
}
```

Comment: +1 for your explanation and not just give the code answer away

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons has a [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) data structure, which has come in handy on more than one occurance that you could check out.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return a single value if you don't want to return an array of boolean. You can decide what to return based on the variables end1 & end2 like

```
public boolean blankEnd() {
    return (this.end1 || this.end2) ? true: false; // Returns true if any variable is 0
}
```

OR

```
public boolean blankEnd() {
    return (this.end1 && this.end2) ? true: false; // Returns true if both variables are 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical and

```
return (this.end1 == 0 && this.end1 == this.end2);
```

Or, you can use logical or by applying [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
return !(this.end1 != 0 || this.end1 != this.end2);
```